# How do I use my skip list node

Tags: c++, skip-lists

I have been stuck on this for 2 months now, tried tutors and internet. I think it's been festering so long that everything I've learned is flying out the window into the garbage can.

I want to declare a skip list node and then use it. I can't figure out how to initialize and access my node arrays. I think the node initializes my arrays to all NULL, but then why can't I set my node arrays index [0] to point to the node index [0] in front of it?

Here is my node:

```html
struct node 
{
    int number;
 node **next; 
 
 node(int &number, int level)
 {
  next = new node*[level];
  for(int i = 0; i<level;i++)
   next[i] = NULL;
  this->number = number;
 }
 
};
```

I don't have a struct for list I am just assembling it in main

```html
int main(){

 node *head = NULL; //create the head sentinel
 node *tail = NULL;  //create the tail sentinel
 char choice;
 int number;
 
 do{
  choice = menu();
  switch(choice){
   case '1':  cout<< "Please enter a number: ";
      cin>> number;
      insert(head, tail, number);
      break;
```

Then I want to attach the headSentinels to my first node.

```html
void insertAsFirstElement(node *&head, node *&tail, int number)
{

 node *temp = new node(number, 3); 
 temp->number = number;
 head->next[0] = temp;
 temp->next[0] = tail; 
 
}
```

If I can figure out how to use the nodes in main then I can figure out the rest of my skip list. Something is tying me up and it's probably easy.

I can compile my program but when I try and insert a number I get a segmentation fault.

I just want to assemble a linked list on the array [0]'s first before I start  making it an actual skip-list

Comment: Is there any good reason for not using `std::forward_list<std::forward_list<int>>`? I think this is what you're trying to have, right? A singly linked list of singly linked lists?

Comment: I am trying to use the array of pointers in my node struct to connect nodes. Once I figure out how to connect the initial level then I will learn how to connect the higher levels to create the skiplist.